# Is it possible to ignore certain modules or paths when deploying modules with ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

We have two environments - two MarkLogic clusters - that are largely identical except we want to permit the POSTing of data to one environment (a pre-production environment) but not the other (production, which is public facing).  We use ml-gradle to deploy modules.  We'd like to ignore or omit the modules/paths of modules that accept the POSTed data when deploying to production.

I cannot find any documentation that describes whether this is possible or how it can be configured if it is possible.  Is it possible?  If so, how?  If it isn't possible, what are our options?  Something like a post-deploy command that then deletes the modules from the production modules database?

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understand correctly. Do you mean you have two parts of modules, and you may which to deploy both sets on pre-prod, and only one on prod? I'd use mlModulePaths property for that, and tweak the value depending on target env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference#module-and-schema-properties - mlModulesRegex is likely what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @rjrudin.

That got me pointed in the right direction.  The solution ended up being a tad odd so I thought I'd report what I did here.

In short, it required a negative lookahead regex:

`mlModulesRegex=(?!.*(Word1InSomePath|Word2InSomePath)).*`